# Add column from df1 into df2 based on the Date column and fill na if df1 [Date] entries are missing

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have dataframe `df1` with 850 rows and column names `['Date', 'A']`.
I also have `df2` with 900 rows and column names `['Date', 'B', 'C', 'D']`.

The difference in their number of rows is because `df1` has some missing 'Date' entries. But, all entries in df1['Date'] are in df2['Date'].

**Question:**
I would like to merge `df1['A']` to `df2` on basis of same `['Date']` rows. After merging, I would like the resultant `df2['A']` to reflect a 'na' for all those rows whose `['Dates']` are missing in `df1`.

I tried `df2=pd.merge(df2, df1, on="Date")` but I get resultant `df2` to have 850 rows which seems that the dates which don't match between df1 and df2 are being deleted. Instead, I would want the post-merged resultant `df2` to be 900 rows and the unmatched date rows should show 'na' in df2['A']`.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `left` join instead of `inner` join (default behavior)

i.e.,

```
new_df = pd.merge(df2, df1, on="Date", how='left')
```

To fill `NA`(as asked by OP in comments) with zero,

```
new_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
# new_df['column'] = new_df['column'].astype(np.float64) # to convert column to float
```

Comment: thank you, your code works. If I would like to substitute the missing n/a entries in `new_df` by zero then how do I accomplish that? I would eventually like to convert the result column to float datatype.

Comment: Please check updated answer